# Hide div cookies javascript issue

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have one problem that is killing me, I try to hide a div for 24h (div that spans a window ) but I do some mistake and it didn't work. Please someone check my test link http://testare.besaba.com, I use bellow code, the error may be in css http://testare.besaba.com/fx.base/site/css/commontest.css where I added this line at the end of the file  #span {display: none;}  . I see the code works fine here jsfiddle.net/Nd4xb/ , only on my site it won't work.

Thank you

Html code :

```
<div id="span" class="promo_header">



  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_promo_header" id="close" onclick="hidePromoPanel('/');"><font color="white">Close </font><span>X</span></a>

<button>Clear cookie</button></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#span').show();
}
/*else {
    $('#span').hide();
}*/


$('#close').click(function () {
    $('#span').slideUp("slow");
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
 });

 $('button').click(function() {
    eraseCookie('hide');
 })

 });

 function hidePromoPanel() {}

 function createCookie(name, value, days) {
 if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
 } else var expires = "";
 document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
 }

 function readCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
 }
 return null;
 }

 function eraseCookie(name) {
 createCookie(name, "", -1);
 } </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  Just built it in jsFiddle but couldnt save it as it's being funny :(

```
<div id="promo" style="display:none">
    Some message here 
    <button>Ok</button>
</div>

<script>
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    if (exdays) exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays) ? '; expires=' + exdate.toUTCString() : '');
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;,]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value !== null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}

if (!getCookie('promo')) {
    document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('promo').getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'none';
    setCookie('promo', '1', 1);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Updated my code. Same result. Maybe because $(".promo_header").slideDown("slow");  are in scripts.js as neustroev say it ?

Comment: Can you close your `<head>` putting the meta tag inside the `<head></head>` and change your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` to bring it up to modern day HTML5 :p

Comment: You also have ` <div class="fxJobs">` without any ending tag :s  Are you new at coding?

Comment: You dont need `$(document).ready(function () {` because the javascript is at the end of the page so gets called last anyway but you will have to move the functions above the `if (!read....` (remember to remove the closing } as well)

Comment: I modified the code directly on my test page http://testare.besaba.com . Cookies don't work.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, can you copy my code again. i put the (exdays) ? '' :';expires=...' the wrong way around in my hast to get you the answer.

Comment: you still have no closing div for fxJobs. It is at the end of `var latestURL = '/jobsSearch/getLatestResults';</div>`. Take it out of there and put it on the end of `<div class="fxJobs">`

Comment: I did it , sorry. Do I have any chance to cookies work for that span ? It may interfere with $(".promo_header").slideDown("slow"); from scripts.js ?

Comment: yes, now in scripts.js, you have under `$(document).ready(function () {` the lines `if ($(".promo_header").length > 0) {$(".promo_header").slideDown("slow"); ....... }` which you should remove otherwise it will always show no matter what cookie is set. You can copy your js code into `http://jsbeautifier.org/` to make it easier to work with.

Comment: thats probably because you already have the promo cookie set. Try it in another browser or clear your browser cookies.

Comment: I cleared my browser. Still no sign of span. Maybe because there is no script left to define/ slide down/up the window?

Comment: `document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'inline';` that line is now in charge of displaying the div.

Comment: the line in scripts.js is still controlling it and displaying the div for me.

Comment: Check it please. there is no sign of that code and no sign of span window. I remove it right now . Though the function hidePromoPanel(a){if($(".promo_header").length>0){$.ajax({url:a,success:function(b){$(".promo_header").slideUp("slow") its still there. Should I remove it too ?

Comment: well, i see the div, i click the button and it goes. then i refresh and its still hidden. i see a cookie set for 24hours. if i manually remove the cookie and refresh, the div is back. Was that not what you were aiming for?? lol

Comment: In Chrome, click on Tools -> Developer Tools, then on the Resources tab, click Cookies. Make sure it isnt in there.

Comment: Oh yes. was preset it to clear cach only :) Yes.Thank you !! . Its not the actual span window I was hoping for . Its only X left now. My beautiful blue window its gone.

Comment: change it to `document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'block'`

Comment: where, in html page, instead of 'none' to put 'block' ? I just did it.

Comment: see my code above, in `if (!getCookie('promo')) {` I changed inline to be block. Your fancy blue box will be back ;)

Comment: Well,it is fine now, my fancy blue box its back! thank you so much for your time! Maybe you can give me your mail, I may kill you sometime with my newbies problems, if you dare.

Comment: sure, you can msn/skype me ccsalway [at] hotmail.com